# Why does this loop never ends?

Tags: javascript

I dont understand why this wont just give me 1 alert instead of infinite alerts.

```
var x=1;

$(document).ready(function(){
  do{
     alert("hey");
     x--;
  }while(x=1);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside while x=1 is not a condition. It is a assignment. Try x==1. Then it will work